# Matching a combination of applicants to positions of a job based on their skills

Tags: algorithm

Essentially I have a job with a fixed number of positions say 3 or 6 and N applicants.

The job requires a number of skills say skills a,b,c,...z.

Applicants have some skills the job requires but likely not all skills.

What I'm struggling to do is constructing an algorithm to match the 3 or 6 applicants such that their combined skills fulfills as many skills the job requires for all situations. Optimistically fulfilling all of them but at worst as many of them as possible

If this is similar or the same to any type of algorithm let me know I can't figure out how to research this.

I've tried thinking of a solution like adding the person who has the most skills the job requires then trying to find the person who has the most skills person 1 didn't have that the job requires. But that falls apart if the solution is a combination of people with a "medium" amount of skills.

I also thought of turning each applicants skills into binary 1 or 0 to signify if they have it but I'm struggling to turn that into something useful. I think doing this might be on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a specific algorithm, but one approach for these sorts of problems is to use a constraint solver/optimizer. For example, in Java you could use [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/).

these are basically declarative systems, so instead of explaining the algorithm you have to program what the problem is. Basically describe the state space, and the constraints for what is or is not a solution. Then you run it, and it will tell you if it found a solution and what solution it found.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this is not a complete solution, but I wanted to share a couple of considerations. Please try and find a better solution.**

So, we have `n` applicants and a set of `m` skills `S = {s(1),s(2),...,s(m)}`.
Each applicant is, for our purposes, a subset `A` of `S` characterizing his/hers skills.
`t` is the number of applicants to choose (for example 3, or 6).

As the OP said, we can represent the skills of each applicant as a string of lenght `m`, where the character at position `i` is 1 if `s(i)` belongs to `A`, and 0 if it doesn't.

**Example**:

```
S = {Programming, Accounting}

            Programming  Accounting
Applicant1       0            1
Applicant2       1            1
```

## Reducing the number of applicants

We can define the following order on the applicants: given two applicants a1 and a2, we say that `a1 <= a2` if, and only if the following statement is true: `if a1 has a skill, then a2 also has it`. In the example above, we have `Applicant1 <= Applicant2`.

Now we can filter the set of our applicants using this order: if an applicant a1 is "below" another applicant a2 in our order, a1 can be discarder, as choosing a2 will always yield at least the same result. This can be done in `O(n^2)` steps.

## Non-optimal, greedy algorithm

Once we have finished, I would proceed this way:

```
r = string of lenght m filled with zeros

choose an applicant a
r = skills(a)
best_applicant = null

APPLICANT_LIST = new LIST
APPLICANT_LIST.add(a)
for(counter=0; counter < (t-1); counter ++)
{
  foreach applicant b not in APPLICANT_LIST
  {
    if (count(skills(b) OR r) > count(r))
    then
      r = (skills(b) OR r) 
      best_applicant = b
  }
  APPLICANT_LIST.add(b)
}
```

Essentially, I would choose an applicant `a` and start with his/hers skill set `r`, and then search the applicant `b` that would add the most skills to my existing set `r` in order to maximize it. I would add `b` to my list, and repeat the process until I have a set of `t` applicants. All of this is done in `O(n^2)` steps (since `t` is constant, I'm ignoring it).
This pseudocode might be incorrect from a programming purpose (depending on the language, you might want to check exit conditions, null pointers, etc.), but I'm sure you get the idea.

I'm afraid this method doesn't always yield the optimal solution, as shown by this example:

```
t = 3

a1  000000001111
a2  000011110000
a3  111100000000
a4  110111001101
```

if one were to start with `a4`, he would never get to the optimal solution `{a1,a2,a3}`.
This is the price we pay for a solution that is optimal at each step, but doesn't consider the problem from a global view.

**Note:** in the example above, choosing a different starting applicant wouldn't help, as a4 would still be included. Might just as well be completely greedy and choose the applicant with the greatest number of skills as our first applicant.

Comment: If someone manages to find an **optimal** solution that also runs in n^2 I'll be happy to delete mine.